# Test my app using iPhone X simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I would like to check the compatibility of my app
to iPhone X using a simulator.

So my question is what is the Xcode and mac OS version that provide iPhone X simulator , and is it available now ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of Xcode 9 GM (available from https://developer.apple.com/download/ if you have an apple developer account) contains a simulator for iPhone X

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode 9 GM Seed](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_GM_seed_build_9A235/Xcode_9_GM_seed.xip) released on Sep 12, 2017.
Click on the link enter your **Apple ID** and **password** and download
Contains iPhone x simulator with iOS 11.